# Can a Gridview have both an onclick and onitemclick listener?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a gridview employing an ImageAdapter. Currently, one can click and long click each individual image in the gridview. I am trying to add functionality so that one can also click the gridview itself, that is to say the space not filled by the ImageAdapter. This is my code for my attempt thus far:

```
mGridViewWords.setAdapter(new AACButtonAdapter(this, button_size, TouchButtonAdapter.TOPIC_WORDS, mDB));

        mGridViewWords.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                AddWordButtonAction((TouchButton) v);
            }
        });
        mGridViewWords.setOnClickListener(new SelectViewListener());

        mGridViewWords.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent_view, View button, int position, long id) {
                removeButtonFromView((GridView)parent_view, position, mCurrentWordCategory);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

however, when trying to use `.setOnClickListener()`, I get this error in Logcat:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead`

Does anyone have advice as to different ways to get the functionality I am after? Can one set two adapters for a gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your GridView takes up the whole screen, one solution would be to place another View under it in a FrameLayout that also fills the whole screen (for example, an ImageView with no android:src specified). If the user clicks an area not occupied by a grid item, the touch event will traverse down to the underlying View, where you can process it as a click in the GridView as you had wanted. Only slightly hacky, but your situation isn't common.

Comment: hm this seems like an idea, however i have 4 gridviews where this would need to happen.